# MYSQL join table with 2 id's

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables that I want to join

Users

> id | name

Matches

> id | user_1 | user_2

now how can I join these tables so I can get information about two users in one query, thank you :)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: This question does not demonstrate any attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do u store in columns user_1, user_2? Which column connect these 2 tables? ANd what do u mean by "get information about two users"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do is below -

```
select 
u1.name as user1, 
u2.name as user2
from matches
inner join users u1 on u1.id = matches.user_1
inner join users u2 on u2.id = matches.user_2
```